# Removal of 'Unregistered' user access

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

Just a quick announcement...

We have noticed over the years, that the vast majority of 'abandoned' questions have come from anonymous, 'unregistered' users - they come along, post an incomplete question, and then never come back to answer the comments the rest of you have added, or indeed to accept or upvote an answer.

Because of this, we have asked the SE admins to disable 'unregistered' users from the site - hopefully this will result in fewer abandoned questions, and more responses to comments and flags.

Comment: Well stated. Thank you, Kind Sir.

Comment: Just to clarify, does this remove the ability of unregistered users to read the questions and answers? Or does it only remove their ability to ask new (soon to be orphaned) questions and leave (possibly abandoned) answers?

Comment: @BobCross - It only removes their ability to post (answers or questions), not to lurk.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I figured but I thought it wouldn't hurt to pre-empt the question! 

Answer (score 0):

Good idea. Perhaps the entire network should by default not allow unregistered users. Sites that want to allow unregistered users can request for an exception (rather than the other way around).

I'm curious how long it took for them to do this for you after you requested it? [**It is taking forever for us**](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/368/5).

Comment: It took about a week, looking back at our chat logs. If you superping one of us in a chat we can give you more details.